# Session not working after memcached activation

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, memcached

I am setting up a Magento store.

The server is running Ubuntu 18.04.5 and Magento 2.4.

After the memcached (service and php extension) installation I updated Magento's session configuration.

Now when i try to access my website i am getting an error.

I need help :/

**Error**

[image]

**Magento session configuration (app/etc/env.php)**

[image]

**PHP session configuration**

[image]

**Linux Memcached information**

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
Have you also commented on the following parameter?
;session.save_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changegd the php.ini "session.save_handler" configuration to "memcached" and it's started to work.